# bug in react-redux, dispatch returns undefined

Tags: react-redux

This is my dispatch code:

```
store.dispatch(addTodo({todo: ' one', significance: 'very'}));
```

This is the action:

```
export const addTodo = ({todo = '', significance = ''} = {}) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  todo,
  significance
});
```

it wires us correctly to the store but when I

```
console.log(store.getState());
```

I get it's in the store, but undefined. Any idea ??

Comment: How's your reducer look like?

Comment: The action looks like this:



export const addTodo = ({ todo = '', significance = ''} = {}) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
todo,
significance
});

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious. Can you try adding console.log(state) and console.log(action) before your switch in reducer?

Comment: Doesn't show up when I add it, the console. I dispatch the actions like this:
store.dispatch(addTodo({todo: 'one', significance: 'very'}));
and in the console I get this:
todos: (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]__proto__: Object